# Homebrew permission issues

Tags: permission, homebrew

I basically installed Homebrew as described at https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation.

However, my user account ist not an Administrator account, therefore I substituted my user identity with the one of user admin (`su - admin`), who is an Administrator. Then, as user admin, I installed Homebrew by executing `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"`. Moreover, I installed giter8 by running `brew update && brew install giter8`.

Now, as user admin I can run command `g8` which is installed in `/usr/local/bin`. However, using my regular restricted user account, I cannot run this command, as its permissions are too restrictive:

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/g8
lrwxr-x---  1 admin  admin  29 Sep  2 11:12 /usr/local/bin/g8 -> ../Cellar/giter8/0.2.0/bin/g8
```

As you can see, `g8` has permissions 750 and is owned by `admin:admin`; so, as regular user, I have no chance to run `g8`. But, what is even more strange, some crucial folders have similar - too restrictive IMHO - permissions:

```
drwxr-x---  3 admin  admin   102 Sep  2 11:12 Cellar
drwxr-x---  7 admin  admin   238 Sep  2 11:12 Library
```

Thus, even after fixing the permissions of symbolic link `g8` (readable and executable by all users), regular users cannot execute commands / run programs installed via `brew install...`, as regular users cannot access folder `Cellar`, nor folder `Library`, which both contain crucial files for most programs.

Is this by design, or is this a bug?

Comment: Nope, my brew permissions are fine and let anyone else on the system use the binaries installed with an admin user. Did you check your `umask`?

Comment: Good point: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/7430

Answer (score 1):

Very old question but I thought I'd mention that some people (including me) `chown` the homebrew `/usr/local/` directory so you can run everything in it without issue. I used:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
```